# Scala: implicit flattening?

Tags: scala

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_27).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def o1: Option[Option[Unit]] = Some(()).map(Some(_))
o1: Option[Option[Unit]]

scala> o1
res0: Option[Option[Unit]] = Some(Some(()))
```

So far all is as expected. But what if we forget to specify that we have an `Option` nested in an `Option`?

```
scala> def o2: Option[Unit] = Some(()).map(Some(_))
o2: Option[Unit]

scala> o2
res1: Option[Unit] = Some(())
```

Why does the compiler accept this and implicitly flatten the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything can be converted to `Unit`:

```
scala> val a: Unit = Some(())
a: Unit = ()
```

For your `o2`, the compiler converts `Some[Unit]` to `Unit`. Note that, of course, it doesn't happen if you replace `Unit` by `Int`, for instance:

```
scala> def o2: Option[Int] = Some(4).map(Some(_))
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Int]
 required: Int
       def o2: Option[Int] = Some(4).map(Some(_))
```

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone was looking for relevant section of Scala Language Specification, it's  6.26.1 (see Value Discarding).